# Joint letters by foreign diplomats to Pakistan

Tags: international-relations

- [Foreign envoys urge Pakistan to condemn Russian invasion of Ukraine during the emergency UNGA session](https://www.dawn.com/news/1677704)

Some foreign diplomats put out a joint letter to the Pakistani government so that Pakistan condemns the Russian invasion.

I have two questions in this regard:

1. How do diplomats decide which government to urge collectively?
2. Did this happen in any other country except Pakistan  (coz, I believe, no similar letter was published in the case of 35 other countries who abstained from voting against Russia)? If NOT, why Pakistan?

---

Note: [A similar incident took place in Turkey a while ago.](https://balkaninsight.com/2021/10/19/turkey-summons-western-diplomats-for-urging-release-of-philanthropist/)

Comment: I can give you a few links about why Pakistan 1)https://www.hindustantimes.com/world-news/imran-khan-in-moscow-says-so-much-excitement-as-russia-declares-war-on-ukraine-101645695091160.html#:~:text=%22What%20a%20time%20I%20have%20come%2C%20so%20much,military%20presented%20a%20guard%20of%20honour%20to%20him. 2)https://www.pakistantoday.com.pk/2022/03/02/pakistan-to-import-wheat-natural-gas-from-russia/#:~:text=Pakistan%20to%20import%20wheat%2C%20natural%20gas%20from%20Russia,attacks%20in%20Ukraine%2C%20according%20to%20the%20prime%20minister.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Background:* [Pakistani Prime minister Imran Khan was the first foreign leader to visit Russia after beginning of the invasion.](https://foreignpolicy.com/2022/02/23/imran-khan-pakistan-russia-putin-india-geopolitics/)

Usually such actions (as a public letter, petition, etc.) are undertaken to put the public pressure on a government and/or discredit the actions of this government in the eyes of the world community and general public.

Pakistan is one of many countries who have strong economic, political and/or military ties with Russia, Ukraine and the countries members of NATO. Obviously both sides are working hard to push these countries from sitting on the fence into unambiguously supporting the preferred cause. Pakistan is either judged to be country requiring just a little push... or it is judged to be leaning towards Russia and the letter might be the last ditch attempt to keep it neutral. Pakistan might be particularly important in connection to India decision to remain neutral, so Pakistan-India rivalry could be exploited to put more pressure on India.